# Nagios Install Plugin for NCPA client via NCPA API

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

Situation: Currently we distribute our custom NCPA scripts on a file share, and the monitoring agents pull the scripts from there. With those custom scripts we check if a service is working properly, because the out of the box checks can't do that.

Idea: we would prefer to distribute the custom NCPA scripts via a continuous integration pipeline.
As NCPA allows me to see all plugins installed on a server with that [API](https://www.nagios.org/ncpa/help.php#api-modules-plugins) `https://localhost:5693/api/plugins?token=mytoken`

I was questioning myself can I install a plugin via that API? Or how do you perform custom checks that are not standard and how do you manage those checks

Thanks in advance for any hints :)